# Socialengine Albums

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm looking for some help in determining how much space the user is using in their albums.  I know I can grab the space limit from the membership level. I assume I can go through the entries in engine4_album_photos and join it on engine4_storage_files?  Has anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance.